# How can I force my textview to display the full text on a single line?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview

I have a `TextView` in my android app that I want to display all the text on a single line. Right now, it is displayed like this:

**this is som

e text**

When I set `setSingleLine()`, I get this:

**this is som e text**
(notice the space within some)

When I use `setMaxLines(1)`, I get this:

**this is som**

What I want is this:

**this is some text**

How can I force the text to display fully on a single line?

Comment: Can your try using the replace method, for example `String value = "a value on two lines"; String value2 = value.replace("\r\n", "");`

Comment: Check this Link : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview.html it will Resize the Text Accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will look into those solutions. Alternatively, do you guys know how to make it so the text displays on multiple lines but doesn't break in the middle of words?

Comment: Its not likely to break the middle of a word when it needs to be shown in another line. Please post a picture of your screen so that we can understand the problem better.

Comment: I am unable to post screenshots of the application. I will try to describe the issue better. Currently, the textview is display text on two lines and is breaking mid word. The first line ends with BL and the second line starts with UETOOTH as oppose to ending the first line with a space and starting the second with the full word BLUETOOTH

Answer (score 0):

You can try this on your textview's xml:

```
android:maxLines="1"
```

Comment: alternatively, do you know how to make it so the text doesn't break mid word when it wraps?

Comment: I think you can not fill your all text, maybe you can try to decrease text size.

Answer (score 0):

You can make scroll text using following code if you want.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtBigLongTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:text="long text goes here......................"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers above provide a solution to my issue.
The problem was the previous programmer had implemented logic which automatically started a new line after 20 characters.'

Thanks for your help everyone!